# Commas in an introductory phrase for both a time shift and a new setting

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

So let’s say I’ve got an introductory phrase that introduces *both* a new setting and a new shift in time, sort of like a “scene change” phrase. For example, let’s say those two elements are “later” for time, and “at a restaurant” for place.

If both of those elements of time and place are completely new in the context of the sentence—not returning to or referring to any pre-established setting—do I need to have a comma after both of those parts (e.g. “Later, at a restaurant, they…”), or just after the full introductory phrase with both elements (e.g. “Later at a restaurant, they…”)?

Can both be acceptable or viable?

Comment: Either one's OK. Say it out loud - do you hear a dip on both ends? If so, use commas there. Otherwise don't.

Comment: By today's standards, two commas could seem precious, bookish, right-but-distracting. Too much help parsing a few words is no compliment to the reader.

Comment: I'd say they're disparate enough to count as _two_ introductory elements. I'd prefer a comma after each. And notice that << Later in the afternoon, >> and << Later, in the afternoon, >> are not synonymous and show the value of the comma / pause in signalling separate elements.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good distinction there.